Пройти испытание войны или войной
Есть ли ошибка в предложении "Князь Андрей с честью проходит испытания войны, показав себя храбрым воином"?

Здесь лучше "испытание (чем?) войной".  Это творительный инструментальный (с помощью войны). Испытание войны  —  родительный определительный (военные испытания, испытания на войне). Как сказано в ответе, этот вариант не ошибка, но стилистика у него хуже, и он менее частотный. Здесь конкуренцию составляет вариант испытания (чего?) войны,  как будто испытывают войну.  На слух это может так восприниматься, что нежелательно.

Тот случай, когда возможны оба варианта. Если автор ставит целью говорить о войне как глобальном явлении, меняющем мировоззрение множества людей, то ваш пример вполне такой позиции соответствует (Империя выдержала успешно испытание войны).
Из НКРЯ: И. судьбы; И. террора; И. пути; И. времени (лет/года/вечера); И. бедственности; И. обстоятельств; И. лжеучений.
Если испытания толкуются как частные проблемы, с которыми случается встретиться каждому, другой вариант будет более уместен (Испытание миром куда вернее испытания войной).
Из НКРЯ: И. властью; И. славой; И. любовью; И. разлукой; И. скорбями.
